# Cast class from asType to class<T,M> : unable to cast

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to cast an object I get with asType(), into it's parent class.

Here is my structure (I think details aren't needed, just classes description and inheritance)

```
    public class Entity1: Entity
    {}
    public class Entity2: Entity
    {}
public class Entity
    {}

public class ClassM1 : MigrationBaseReverse<Entity1, Entity2>
    {}

public class MigrationBaseReverse<T, M> : MigrationBase<T, M>
        where T : Entity, new()
        where M : Entity, new()  
    {}

 public class MigrationBase<T, M>
        where M : Entity, new()
        where T : Entity, new()
    {}
```

What I do :

I stored the type info of ClassM1 like this (ti is a TypeInfo) :

```
Type type = ti.AsType();
```

Then, I create a new instance with Activator

```
instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I then (or irectly in Activator, but got the same result), try to cast it as it's parent like this

```
instance as MigrationBase<Entity, Entity>
```

But this doesn't work, and I got null, while this obviously works

```
instance as MigrationBase<Entity1, Entity2>
```

As Entity1 and Entity2 inherit from entity, I would have think that I could use Entity instead, but seems not.

I also tried a cast like this :

```
(MigrationBase<Entity1, Entity2>) instance
```

But I get an error in the cast like this :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ClassM1' to type 'MigrationBase`2[Entity,Entity]'.
```

I should add that I tried all those casts with  MigrationBaseReverse

Any ideas would be appreciated.

I was not sure about the title, as it's complicated to explain, so if one know a better title, then don't be afraid of an edit.

I hope you I got you all informations needed.

Comment: what is `it` variable ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Agreed, at least to clear up if Entity is Entitybase.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance may be of use to you.

Comment: @HenkHolterman my mistake, I mis transcript from my code.
mjwills : Even if my code isn't specific, I wrote all the stages of my code, but I could gather it in one block. It seems to me that I explain what I expect, what I got, maybe the code executed isn't clear?

Answer (score 4):

This question is asked 1000 times every week on SO.

First of all, generic type variance in c# is only allowed on interfaces and delegates. You have neither.

Second, in order to allow type variance, you must prove it's safe. An `IList<string>` is *not* an `IList<object>` because the conversion is simply unsafe; `IList<T>` is *invariant* in `T`.

An `IEnumerable<string>` *is* an `IEnumerable<object>` because `IEnumerable<out T>` is *covariant* in `T`.

With the code you have provided it's impossible to determine if a theoretical `IMigrationBase<T, M>` can be covariant in `T` and `M`. If it *can*, then your conversion will work, if it can't then it won't.

A very useful read on the subject: [Covariance and Contravariance in C# series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/). Be sure to read part six.

UPDATE:

Ok, imagine your theoretical `IMigrationBase<T, M>` looked like this:

```
interface IMigrationBase<T, M>
    where T: Entity
    where M: Entity
{
    M Migrate(T entity) { .... }
}
```

And imagine this were legal:

```
var m1 = new ClassM1();
IMigrationBase<Entity, Entity> m = m1; //illegal but lets play along
```

We could then have the following terrible idea:

```
m.Migrate(new Entity3()); //Legal but ouch!
```

And now `m`, which is really `m1`, is suddenly trying to migrate an `Entity3` type it knows nothing about. This happens because the interface is not covariant in `T` (its covariant in `M` but contravariant in `T`), the conversion can never be safe. The true declaration of this theoretical interface, if you want type variance, would be `IMigrationBase<in T, out M>` and the following conversion would be safe:

```
IMigrationBase<Entity1, Entity> m = m1;
```

If your interface were to be covariant in `T` and `M` then the conversion you are attempting would be safe. How can you know if its covariant in `T` and `M`? Well, the rule of the thumb (not 100% exact, but good enough most of the time), is that `T` and `M` should only ever be outputs (`out`) of the interface members, never inputs (`in`). If your interface needs to use one of its generic types as an input then it can never be covariant in that generic type parameter.

Comment: So, if I get it well, I need to add an interface `IMigrationBase<Entity,Entity>` , add `IMigrationBase<TEntity1, TEntity2>` to `ClassM1`, but Entity1 and Entity2 (or Entity) must be covariant if I want to succeed anyway. But I don't get how to make them covariant. I am not used to that, so I may be slow with this.

Comment: @provençallebreton Well, the obvious recommendation is to first understand what you are trying to do and then try to do it. Doing it without fully understanding it is not a compelling coding practice. Read and study the series I've linked (its a total of 10 parts). Some of the stuff there will give you a headache but if you read it carefully enough to *understand* it, you wont be asking anything more about covariance and contravariance on SO, I assure you.

Comment: I read all those articles. I think I didn't understand them well, because I don't succeed transpose this in my particular case. I will ask a colleague (when available) that could explain this to me more clearly in my own language, that could help.
But as ClassM1 always receives Entity1 and Entity2, which are Entity, then for me it should be Ok because `IMigrationBase`will always receives Entity. But obviously, I didn't understand it well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @provençallebreton Added an example to illustrate how it all *does* relate to your present issue.

Comment: Ok, i understand a little better. And you mean that if I got a function like  `bool Migrate(T entity) { .... } ` , my interca can't be covariant, which means I will have to found something else to do what I want? Because T is used as a parameter in the function.
Because indeed, if I remove my function and put `IMigrationBaseReverse<out T, out M>`, then I get my object fine. I will have to figure out how I can do what I want, this in fact make a huge differences, while a though a function in my interface would not affect the issue (I wasn't using an interface at start).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @provençallebreton Exactly, you are understanding it correctly. If your interface can't be covariant due to the functionality you need then the conversion can't be done.